# Django: Access "through" model from ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django (1.9) I want to access the implicitly defined intermediary model given the `field` that creates the relations. Let's say I have the models

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ManyToManyField('Author')

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I get the intermediary model class as

```
Book.author.through
```

and I get an object with similar attributes via

```
Book._meta.get_field('author').remote_field.through()
```

However, I'm facing the problem that the object returned by `through()` once does not equal in object returned by `through()` the next time. Can I somehow directly obtain the class `Book.author.through` from the field and what is the idea behind `through()`?

Answer (score 4):

The answer was quite simple. `Book._meta.get_field('author').remote_field.through` will indeed give you the same class as `Book.author.through`. This class is obviously callable a by using `through()` you instantiate a new instances of that class that are unequal to each other as instances usually are. It was only the auto complete in the Python shell that led me to believe that `remote_field.through` needs to be called.